# Is there an actionscript open source library that implements photo effects like http://www.flasheff.com/patternsshowcase/

Tags: actionscript-3

I am an actionscript 3.0 beginner,I need an open source tools implementing photo effects like http://www.flasheff.com/patternsshowcase/ for example in my project. who can give me some useful suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean this: http://www.flasheff.com/freedownload.html  ^_-

Comment: @MartyWallace The free version can be fully used for trial purposes. For commercial purpose you will need to get a commercial license (single-user or multi-user). Does this sound free enough for you. for me not!

Answer (score 0):

Either use [greensock](http://www.greensock.com/) actionscript library, which is free and amazing, to create the effects you want,

or

check out the list here: http://www.webappers.com/2010/01/07/best-places-to-get-quality-flash-components/ which includes Flash-library-and-effects auction sites, and potentially cheap or open-source solutions.